# Interface methods to return dynamic

Tags: c#, interface, dynamictype

Would there be any downside if, as of .NET 4.0's release, all interface methods were changed from returning **object** to returning **dynamic**?

Existing code would not have to be altered due to it since the underlying type would still be the same and it would make for slightly less verbose code.

```
public class MyClass : IClonable
{
    //...
    public object Clone()
    {
        //...
        return new MyClass(...);
    }
}

MyClass foo = new MyClass(...);
MyClass bar = foo.Clone() as MyClass;
```

The only reduction to the verbosity of the code above is changing the declaration of **foo** and **bar** to **var**.

Now, if **IClonable.Clone()** returned a **dynamic** instead, the underlying class (at runtime) would still be **MyClass**, but the code would become slightly less verbose:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass(...);
MyClass bar = foo.Clone();
```

Would there be any downside to such a change?

Comment: You should use `as` only if you follow it with a `null` check. If you don't want to do that, use a cast instead, e.g. `MyClass bar = (MyClass)foo.Clone();`.

Comment: Also, I think the right solution here is to avoid `ICloneable` altogether, not trying to work around its issues.

Answer (score 5):

One downside to this change would be compiler's inability to catch errors caused by typos. For example, if you wrote

```
if (foo.Clone().Equalls(foo)) {
//                  ^^
//                  ||
// Here is a typo ==++
}
```

with your `Clone()` returning an `object`, the compiler would catch it. With a change to `dynamic` the compiler would take it fine, so your program would throw a runtime exception for a missing method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one major downside would be that dynamics do not provide compile-time safety... or useful intellisense for that matter. So not only would it take longer and be more error prone accessing a property on an object, but if you did make a mistake, you wouldn't catch it until runtime.

It won't always be the case, but often the example of "verbosity" you give could be better avoided by generics. `ICloneable` is an example of an interface where for some reason (possibly historic) there is no generic version, but when there is a generic version, it means that you can return the exact type you need rather than an object that must be cast.

Comment: The compile-time safety issue would only occur in cases such as described by @dasblinkenlight, where a member is accessed directly from the method (foo.Clone().Member). This is a very valid observation and something that hadn't occurred to me yet, but compile-time safety and Intellisense are maintained in other cases (such as the ones I presented in the OP).

Comment: @Wasabi Yes, if it's assigned to a strongly typed variable then it's no worse than a cast. But I don't think it's a safe assumption that that will always be appropriate, especially in the case of properties rather than methods. Having to assign those to variables could actually lead to much more boilerplate rather than less